# How to add taskbar widget in flutter desktop?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

I want to add window taskbar widget with flutter desktop. An example would be weather widget that is optionaly displayed on the right corner of taskbar (before system tray icons).

Is there an exposed API or library to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/system_tray

Comment: System tray is not what I'm looking for because you are limited to static image for display. I need a way to display dynamic UI in the widget attached to taskbar. 

Additionally wheather widget shown in a pic is not a system tray as it precedes expandable system tray menu